# Flask / Heroku / Redis / RQ Internal Server Error

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis

I have a recommendation site. Everything was working dandy, until at points when the site was under a decent amount of traffic, the recommendations would take longer than 30 seconds (Heroku's limit) and time-out, throwing a 500 error. I realize this is a very long time for a http request.

So, I read up online and implemented RQ with Redis. I got that to work, but after some testing, it will still throw the Internal Server Error, even though the requests are going through a queue.

I'm really just lacking knowledge here and I have no idea what to do. I think I'm missing the whole idea of rq and redis I guess? Here's some of my code if it helps, but I'm hoping for more of just guidance of where to go from here to fix this error.

worker.py

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL',
                      'redis://redistogo:sampleurl:portNo/')
if not redis_url:
    raise RuntimeError('Set up Redis to go first.')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__=='__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

part of my views.py

```
q = Queue(connection=conn)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    form = ArtistsForm()
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)


@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    form = ArtistsForm()
    error = None
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            table = 'Artists'
            artists = []
            for value in form.data.items():
                if (value[1] is not ''):
                    artists.append(value[1])

            results = q.enqueue_call(func=getArtists, args=(table, *artists))
            while results.result is None:
                time.sleep(1)
            results = results.result.values.tolist()

            return render_template('results.html', results=results)
        else:
            error = "Please be sure to enter 5 artists with correct spelling" \
                    " and punctuation"

    except pylast.WSError:
        return render_template('error.html')
    return render_template('home.html', form=form, error=error)
```

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: What is te error message?

Comment: It's just 500 Internal Server. On Heroku logs, it's H12 - Timeout (because request takes longer than 30 sec)

Comment: Don't you have errors on local/dev environment?

Comment: Nope, it runs fine locally. Like I was saying, this gets caused when there's traffic on the site. It takes the requests and calculations to run a bit longer, resulting in the timeout error. What I'm trying to do is find a way to prevent the time out error, which occurs every now and then.

Comment: Maybe, you need to upgrade you Redis plan. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can always try dividing the work between a web dyno to simply acknowledge the request, then have worker dynos doing the heavy lifting.

Kafka or something similar could be used to accomplish this.