# How do I resolve Heroku Redis error using Flask App

Tags: flask, heroku, redis

I have used information from link to add activate Redis queue in my Flask app:
[Heroku Redis](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq)

Following is the code in my app file.

```
from worker import conn
q = Queue(connection=conn)

@app.route('/pureredis', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def pureredis():
  import createtable
  file = q.enqueue(createtable.test_task(),'http://heroku.com')
  return file
```

What I want here is to simply call test_task() from createtable.py file and show results in /pureredis

Meanwhile I have added a worker.py file to instantiate a conn.

Error I am getting is as follows:

```
2023-01-03T01:50:23.899221+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rq/utils.py", line 147, in import_attribute
raise ValueError('Invalid attribute name:   %s' % name)
ValueError: Invalid attribute name: {
```

I checked out some earlier tickets and tried but that did not help.
[stockoverflow redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287399/flask-heroku-redis-rq-internal-server-error)

Information in link below is good but does not work for Heroku:
[flask with redis](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function inside the `enqueue` function remember this expects a `Callable`

from this

```py
job = q.enqueue(createtable.test_task(),'http://heroku.com')
```

to this

```py
job = q.enqueue(createtable.test_task,'http://heroku.com')
```

Remember to return a valid response in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to OP's issue, but I had similar errors:

```
2023-08-31T11:58:37.037006+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/utils.py", line 109, in import_attribute
2023-08-31T11:58:37.037006+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise ValueError('Invalid attribute name: %s' % name)
2023-08-31T11:58:37.037007+00:00 app[worker.1]: ValueError: Invalid attribute name: mymodule.myfunction
```

Solution:
The module I imported was missing dependencies.
In my case the `mymodule.myfunction` was utilizing `requests` so I added `requests` to `requirements.txt` and problem was solved.